# Kendo UI Grid in MVC - How to return selected row Item to Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 4 application with a Kendo UI grid that I am using for user management. I display the users information in the grid and have a custom command button that when clicked opens a new page to edit the users information. For various reasons (one being there is too much information to be edited to display in the grid) I need to edit the users on a new page and not with inline or popup or incell editing. My grid looks like this... very simple

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WebSiteNew.Models.ManageUsersViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-top: 5px" })
.Columns(c =>
{
    c.Bound(model => model.UserName);
    c.Bound(model => model.FirstName);
    c.Bound(model => model.LastName);
    c.Bound(model => model.Email);
    c.Bound(model => model.Phone);
    c.Bound(model => model.Extension);
    c.Bound(model => model.JobTitle);
    c.Command(com => { com.Custom("Edit").Click("edit"); com.Destroy(); });
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Selectable()
.DataSource(d => d
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Model(m => m.Id(i => i.UserName))
    .Read(r => r.Action("ManageUsers_Read", "ManageUsers"))
    .Destroy(o => o.Action("ManageUsers_Destroy", "ManageUsers"))
))
```

The issue I have here is that I need to pass the ID of the user that the edit button has been clicked on to the edit screen so that I can bring up the information for the selected user. The only way I know of to get this information is through javascript, something like this in my command button click function...

```
function edit() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var row = grid.select();
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
    var id = dataItem.UserId;

    location = "@Url.Action("EditUser")";
}
```

This gives me the id that I need but I have no way (that I know of) to pass this back to my controller. So my question is... how do I get this information back to the server side? Is there another way to get the information I need or is this just something that is not possible in Kendo UI MVC?

To make this a more general question.. when I look at the Kendo UI documentation and it tells me how to get a value in javascript... how, in general, does one go about using this value in an MVC application when it is needed on the server side? I can't seem to find an alternative "MVC" way to do this in their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should form additional parameters to url string:

```
location = "@Url.Action("EditUser")" + "?id="+id;
```

Comment: That is one way to do it, however what if you don't want to expose the id to your controller? is there another way to do this for example passing the whole dataItem to the Controller from the parameter?